# How long do HWE kernels maintain/support in Ubuntu?

Tags: upgrade, kernel, hardware-enablement-stack

I tried 3.19.x.x.lts-vivid kernel and it doesn't seem to work with my hardware as I cannot build a module for my Nvidia graphic card and there are also similar bug reports submitted and confirmed to Launchpad.

So, if I'm using 14.04.2LTS with its default HWE kernel stack which is a default kernel of Ubuntu 14.10 Utopic also and 14.10 development will be finished in July 2015 and thus will be an EOL release.

Then for how long I can use its kernel 3.16.x.x in my 14.04.2LTS HWE stack? Will it be maintained including security updates or do I need to upgrade to further kernel or wait and upgrade when the next point release is out?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what NVIDIA card do you have?

Comment: The only reason I asked that, is that I am running Kernel 4.0.5 now on my host, and I have a NVIDIA 8800GT, where I had to patch a file with some lines, and I was able to build my NVIDIA driver with the newer kernels without issues.  The patch info can be found here:  https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/813458/linux/linux-4-0-rc1-346-35-build-error-_cr4-functions-fix/

Comment: @Terrance it's an old Nvidia that runs on driver 304.x similar issue happened to me a year ago but Nvidia commited a fix themselves in the update to 304.x so I guess they'll do it again as usual, it just takes time but I'm not that in a hurry. ;)

Comment: No problem.  I was running the 304 drivers for a while too, and they worked fine for me.  Sometimes I love the challenge of fixing things, so I am running the 340.76 drivers.  Just thought I would share.

Comment: I take that back.  I just installed all kernels from Trusty (3.13) thru Wily (4.0.5).  All were able to install with the NVIDIA 340.76 driver using that patch, and I left the `#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE < KERNEL_VERSION(3, 20, 0)` line intact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see it in the table

[image]

You can use 3.13 till 14.04 EOL in 2019.

3.16 will be supported till August 2016.

More general

[image]

Comment: yes and out of this seems like I can use it 'til August 2016 isn't it? so it means it will be supported and maintained with updates 'til then?

Comment: ok then it seems like I can wait for the final point release or even upgrade to the next LTS release if so. Thanks ;) P.S. just don't want to upgrade to 3.19.x.x kernel there are appears to be a lot of bugs with this one especially talking of HWE support. And in kernel.org is also marked as dead (eol)

Comment: Don't worry about eol at kernel.org. Canonical supports these kernels same way as mainstream does. I am involved a little bit in this process too. And 3.19 is not bad.

Comment: maybe so but it doesn't currently working with my hardware and this report marked as `high` in [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-304-updates/+bug/1431278) it's 3.19 and 4.0 also.

Comment: You can install nvidia-304 from xorg-edgers. They fixed it. Same driver.

Comment: Ok thanks @Pilot6 I'll try some workarounds later but I guess I can stick to 3.16.x.x for now anyways, probably compatability will be fixed officialy by the time. ;)